# Does Power Functions 88002 fit a gray-era train and run on gray-era tracks?

Tags: trains, power-functions

Is the Power Functions Train Motor (set [88002](https://brickset.com/sets/88002-1/Train-Motor)) the right height for a gray-era train (set [7745](https://brickset.com/sets/7745-1/High-Speed-City-Express-Passenger-Train-Set))? Does the Power Functions Train Motor run OK on gray-era tracks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen in this video, it is possible to add Power Functions to set [7745](https://brickset.com/sets/7745-1/High-Speed-City-Express-Passenger-Train-Set) and run the train on gray tracks

[Lego Train 7745 with Power Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EB6Qx08gfyk)

[image]
photo from [Brickshelf gallery](http://www.brickshelf.com/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi?f=481712)

Another video
[Lego 7745 powerfunktion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TV9ANED5zQ)